# how to use ember-simple-oauth2 authenticate from imy CustomAuthenticator

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am able to successfully authenticate using my own customAuthenticator.

I need to use a customAuthenticator as the authenticating back end server requires the 
request header to have the client_id and client_secret.

Something like this.

```
  headers: {
           "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(credentials.client_id + ":" +  
            credentials.client_secret) ,

           "API-KEY": window.ENV.api_key
           },
```

however i see there are several utility functions inside the simple-auth-oauth2.js files
which the authenticate method uses.

Methods like : 
                absolutizeExpirationTime(response.expires_in);
               scheduleAccessTokenRefresh(response.expires_in, expiresAt, response.refresh_token);

My question is how do i call these methods inside simple-auth-oauth2 from my customAuthenticator.

I dont want to copy these methods into my customAuthenticator file.....

Answer (score 0):

You can simple define a custom authenticator that extends the OAuth 2.0 authenticator. The only method you have to override is `makeRequest`, e.g.:

```
var CustomAuthenticator = Authenticators.OAuth2.extend({
  makeRequest: function(url, data) {
    data.client_id     = …;
    data.client_secret = …;
    return this._super(url, data);
  }
})
```

Comment: But how do i customize the request header..the authenticating backend service expects the request header to have the client_id and client_secret injected to header like this :headers: {
           "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(credentials.client_id + ":" +  
            credentials.client_secret) ,

           "API-KEY": window.ENV.api_key
           },

Comment: If you want to set a header you have to override `makeRequest` without calling `_super` but instead invoke `Ember.$.ajax` yourself and specify the `headers` option.